# Vue.js: correct way to set up a "detail component"

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have a list of post objects and I'm now wanting to set up a detail page/component for each post. In my component where I have the list I do the following:

Dashboard.vue:

```
<template>
    <div v-for="post in posts" v-bind:key="post.id">
        <router-link :to="{ name: 'post', params: { id: post.id }}">{{post.post_description}}</router-link>
    </div>
</template>
```

So, we have a list of links. When I click on a link the "Post" component is displayed:

Post.vue:

```
<template>
    <div>
        Post
        {{ $route.params.id }} <!-- The post ID of whichever we clicked on -->
    </div>
</template>
```

I'm not sure how I should pass the post object (the one that was clicked on) to the post component. I have the ID of the post via `$route.params.id`, so I could set up a route on the server side to get a post by ID, and then make a GET request to that route from the post component, but this seems wrong since I already have access to the object from the Dashboard component.

In Vue.js when using vue-router, how should a "detail" component like this be set up? Can I somehow pass the object as a prop to the `router-link` and access that within Post.vue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you can store all posts in global store using [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/).

You can get the post id and find the specific post in your Post component,

for example, using `beforeRouteUpdate (to, from, next) {`

```
{
   beforeRouteUpdate (to, from, next) {
     const { id } = to.params
     // set your post, for example
     this.$store.state.posts.find(post => post.id === id)
     next()
   }
}
```

Comment: After adding `beforeRouteUpdate ` to my Post component, when navigating from `/` to `/posts/1` , `beforeRouteUpdate` never seems to be called. But this does seem like the right approach. +1